# Bug in parallelStream in java

Tags: java, filter, stream, reduce, parallelstream

Can someone tell me why this is happening and if it's expected behaviour or a bug

```
List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(1,1,3,3);

a.parallelStream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .filter(value -> value > 2)
        .reduce(1,Integer::sum)
```

Answer: `10`

But if we use `stream` instead of `parallelStream` I'm getting the **right & expected** `answer 7`

Comment: check [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#reduce(int,java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator)) of `reduce`: *"...The identity value must be an identity for the accumulator function. This means that for all `x`, `accumulator.apply(identity, x)` is equal to `x`..."* - not the case for `1` and `Integer::sum`

Comment: to be able to use parallel streams, the reducing is done in parts, each part is adding one (probably once for each element) - try it with `0` and the result should be correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument to reduce is called "identity" and not "initialValue".

`1` is no identity according to addition. `1` is identity for multiplication.

Though you need to provide `0` if you want to sum the elements.

---

Java uses "identity" instead of "initialValue" because this little trick allows to parallelize `reduce` easily.

---

In parallel execution, each thread will run the reduce on a part of the stream, and when the threads are done, they will be combined using the very same reduce function.

Though it will look something like this:

```
mainThread:
  start thread1;
  start thread2;
  wait till both are finished;

thread1:
  return sum(1, 3); // your reduce function applied to a part of the stream

thread2:
  return sum(1, 3);

// when thread1 and thread2 are finished:
mainThread:
  return sum(sum(1, resultOfThread1), sum(1, resultOfThread2));
  = sum(sum(1, 4), sum(1, 4))
  = sum(5, 5)
  = 10
```

I hope you can see, what happens and why the result is not what you expected.

Comment: But then why is the result different in case of stream?

Comment: Because non-parallel stream works sequentially. I'll provide an example in my answer in a few minutes

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin this was quite helpful.

Comment: Just interesting: the algorithm is a bit different - `identity` is being added even if values are filtered out: `IntStream.range(0, 100).parallel().filter(v  -> v < 0).reduce(1,Integer::sum)` (`36` with jshell 1.15)

Comment: @user15244370 Yeah. And the result depends on the number of threads being used. You example gives: `4` for 1 thread, `12` for 2 threads, `20` for 4 threads, and `36` for 8 threads. I guess there's a chunk size in addition to the thread count, so that every thread only computes N elements at a time, and after it's finished it will get the next N elements.